# How do I access an Eclipse Tomcat server externally?

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat6

I am trying to access an Apache Tomcat v6.0 server running inside Eclipse (OsX) on port 8090 on a machine that is on a different network. I have tried `http://my_public_ip:8090/` and it is not working and googling hasn't turned up anything that worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a Windows machine?  If so, is Windows Firewall turned on?  If so, have you added an exception for port 8090 and/or java.exe (maybe javaw.exe)?

In what way is it not working?

Comment: The server is running on a Mac. The browser is getting no response and  the page just times out.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not a Mac expert but doesn't it have some kind of personal firewall type of thing too?  You'd also have to open the port if you have an external firewall and/or do port forwarding if you have a router.

Comment: I ended up doing port forwarding with my router and it solved my problem. Thanks!